# Approval Process : what if the Approver misspells the Approval/rejection word?

Tags: email, email-template, approval-process

When submitting for approval, there’s an email going to the next approver. This email should have a key word on 1st line, it can also show the comment the submitter captured when submitting for approval.

I understand that the approver can reply using specific words as Approve/Rejected, YES or NO to the email in the first line to get the approval approved/rejected, and the secobd line will be captured as a comment..Now, what if he misspells the Approval/rejection word? or forgets to use it..Will the response be lost, or will he receive an error email?

Answer (score 0):

The user will receive a message with

> Your workflow approval message was not processed. The word used to approve or reject the item was not understood.
>
> Please contact your system administrator if you feel you received this message in error

Comment: Thanks Sergio !